# How to prove this arguments in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I have the following premise:
\begin{gather}
    ¬B⟹D \\
    ¬A⟹C
\end{gather}

And I have to prove this formula:
$$
    ¬(A\vee B)⟹C \wedge D
$$
I'm allowed to use only the following rules I$\wedge$, E$\wedge$, I$\vee$, E$⟹$, I$⟹$, I$¬$, E$¬$, E$\vee$, it.

I understand the rules. But in this problem I don't know how to start. 
I'm a beginner in natural deduction.

Comment: Are you sure about the first premise ? Maybe $\lnot B \to D$ ...

Comment: Yes! Sorry... edited

Comment: How is $ I \neg$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

With [Natural Deduction rules](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4):

1) $\lnot B \to D$ --- premise

2) $\lnot A \to C$ --- premise

3) $\lnot (A \lor B)$ --- assumed [a]

4) $A$ --- assumed [b]

5) $A \lor B$ --- from 4) by $\lor$I

6) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\lnot$E

7) $\lnot A$ --- from 4) and 6) by $\lnot$I, discharging [b]

*Note*: without $\bot$, probably your $\lnot$I rule allows you to derive $\lnot \varphi$ after a derivation of a contradiction from the assumption $\varphi$. If so, you can skip 6) and justify 7) with: from 4), 3) and 5) by $\lnot$I, discharging [b].

8) $C$ --- from 2) and 7) by $\to$E

9) $B$ --- assumed [c]

In the same way as before, we derive a contradiction, frow which derive $\lnot B$ (discharging [c]) and with 1) we derive (by $\to$E) :

10) $D$

> 11) $C \land D$ --- from 8) and 10) by $\land$I
>
> > 12) $\lnot (A \lor B) \to (C \land D)$ --- from 3) and 12) by $\to$I, discharging [a].

Comment: Sorry maybe I have to explain better my questions. But I don't understand the meaning of ⊥. We didn't study that. We can't use derivative rules in this exercise. Thanks for show me how to start!

Comment: @JosepB - I've understood that you are "a beginner in natural deduction", but I've assumed that you have at least studied the rules of ND.

Comment: Yes, maybe in the next units we study the meaning of ⊥. Anyway I'll google it. Thanks @Mauro

Comment: @JosepB - I've linked a good on-line presentation of ND and its rules exactly to support my proof; maybe you have to provide in your question the list of rules you are allowed to use...

Comment: You're right @Mauro. I edited the question with the rules that I'm allowed to use.